# Using statement without specific implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class which inherits from WebClient - in some code I am trying to test there is the usual:

```
using(var client = new SomeWebClient()){...}
```

Now I don't want to use that `SomeWebClient` class in my tests so I'd like to inject in some kind of stub.

Without using the servicelocator pattern what are my options? I can't use any real IoC as this assembly is used by multiple platforms both mobile and full .NET

I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but I think I'm having "one of those days"!

Comment: Can you change the code you want to test?

Comment: I can but nothing huge

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what is preventing you from using a DI framework. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Create something that inherits from `SomeWebClient`. Override all the functions there and use this in the test code (just exchange this one line which you have shown). Not perfect, but fulfills the requirements.

Comment: This code is being used by Xamarin on Android and iPhone platform as well as full blown .NET on the server - using an IoC would mean having to use IoC across all platforms - too big a change to consider atm - unless of course there really is no other option I guess

Comment: Well, the first requirement for being able to use some kind of stub is to use an abstraction (abstract class or interface) in your using statement instead of var. Then it depends on your project where you get the concrete implementation. You could either pass it to your code as a parameter or use a factory.

Comment: I dont get it. You can create a common interface, make SomeWebClient implement this interface and write the stub implementing the same interface and use DI framework only in the project where you want to test.

Comment: OK - I am probably being stupid here but without using service locator - how do I say using(var client = new ISomeWebClient()) ?

Comment: What I meant was using (ISomeWebClient client = ...)
The ... can be a call to a factory or (probably better) an instance that you pass to your code from the outside (that's what inversion of control is all about: Don't create your dependencies yourself, have your caller provide them)

Comment: I have done something similar - I've added an optional Func<ISomeWebClient> param to the ctor and do a ternary on that in the using statement - of there is a func passed in it will use that otherwise fall back to the default implementation. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Is `SomeWebClient` the actual class under test or do you want to test the calling method?

Comment: Well, that's basically a factory ;)

Comment: Yuhp - that's where I got the idea from :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Use an interface

```
using(ISomeWebClientc = new SomeWebClient()){...}
```

2a) Create a factory that returns an ISomeWebClient implementation.

3) Let it return your correct class in the production code or let it create a stub in your tests.

2b) Alternatively, just pass an ISomeWebClient to your class or method and initialize it differently in your test or production code.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a `Func<TResult>`. This `Func` is then called in your `using` statement, like so:

```
using (ISomeClient client = InjectedFunc())
{
    ...
}

public delegate Func<ISomeClient> InjectedFunc();

...
```

Then somewhere in your code you assign this `Func` a value, which is a code block to be executed later:

```
InjectedFunc = delegate(){ return new MyImplementation(); };
// or some other way of creating a new instance, as long as
// you return a fresh one
```

and so, this is functionally the same as if your using block would say:

```
using (ISomeClient client = new MyImplementation())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `delegate` instead of the more succinct lambda syntax? `() => new MyImplementation()`